# How to remove blocks of code that starts/ end with some specific pattern in vim?

Tags: vim

I wonder whether there is some way **within** *vim* to remove all block of code whose first/last line match a specific pattern. For instance, I have a  c++ code with a lot of #if #endif blocks   I want to get rid of:

```
#if GGSDEBUG  ---|
somecode        Block to delete
#endif        ---|

//code

#if GGSDEBUG  ---|
somecode        Block to delete
#endif        ---|

//code

#if GGSDEBUG  ---|
somecode        Block to delete
#endif        ---|
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `:global` command to locate all start lines of your blocks, and execute a command there.

```
:g/^#if GGSDEBUG/ [...]
```

As the cursor is placed on that first line of the block, you can `:delete` the block by specifying a *range* that ends with a pattern describing your end of the block:

```
:.,/^#endif/delete
```

Put together:

```
:g/^#if GGSDEBUG/.,/^#endif/delete
```

You can adapt the patterns (e.g. by appending `\n\zs$` to `endif` to also remove the following empty line).

Comment: It worked like a charm...  Thank you... One last question.. Is it possible to confirm the deletion of each matched block using the same command structure? (I mean using :g instead of :%s/../../gc)

Comment: Not so easy, there's no such flag. You have to prepend a conditional before the `:delete` command, such as: `if confirm('Change?', "&Yes\n&No") == 1 | .,/^#endif/delete | endif`

Answer (score 4):

For C code, you can use the built-in matching behavior:

```
:g/^#if\>/normal!V%d
```

This handles nesting properly.  (At least, it should, and in my little test it does.)  For other languages, use matchit and drop the <kbd>!</kbd>:

```
:runtime macros/matchit.vim
:e foo.html
:g/^<table>/normal Vh%d
```

```
:help :normal
:help %
:help matchit-install
:helptags $VIMRUNTIME/macros
:help matchit-%
```

Comment: Awesome. As an explanation for what is happening here (I had to look it up): benjifisher uses the "normal!" command to use normal navigation commands on the command line. "V" starts the select mode, "%" finds the matching #endif for the #if under the cursor, "d" deletes it.

Comment: @Jan: right.  Just "Normal commands" or "Normal-mode commands," not "normal navigation commands."  Also, ":normal!" means not to use mappings, which is why I leave it out when using matchit.  I will edit the answer to include a reference for `:normal`.  Also, there are three Visual modes; `V` enters line-wise Visual mode.

Answer (score 2):

From within one of those blocks, you can use this variant of Ingo's answer:

```
:?^#if GGSDEBUG?,/^#endif/d

:?pattern before the cursor?,/pattern after the cursor/delete
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this: It will automatically remove **all** occurrences in the file.

It makes use of a non-greedy search `\{-}` (in place of *) and uses `\(.\|\n\)` (in place of a simple ".") in the pattern to extend of multiple lines:

```
:%s/^#if GGSDEBUG\(.\|\n\)\{-}#endif//g
```

Note: If you have nested blocks that end with #endif, it will only delete until the first one. But this will be a limitation of all solutions here, I guess.

Comment: FWIW, you can include newline in a character class with `\_` prefix, e.g. `:%s/^#if GGSDEBUG\_.\{-}#endif//g` is equivalent. <3 vimgolf